# Why does memcpy() cause a crash?

Tags: c, algorithm, crash, string-matching, memcpy

I am trying to run an implementation of the Hashq algorithms (string matching algorithm). It was written for POSIX, but I am trying to run in Code Blocks on Windows.

The implementation is:

```c
#define RANK5 5
#define WSIZE 256 // greater int value fitting in a computer word
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int search(unsigned char *x, int m, unsigned char *y, int n) {
    int count, i, j, sh, shift[WSIZE], sh1, mMinus1, mMinus4;
    unsigned int h;
    if (m < 5)
        return -1; // substring or pattern has to be greater than 4

    /* Preprocessing */
    // BEGIN_PREPROCESSING
    count = 0;
    mMinus1 = m - 1;
    mMinus4 = m - 4;
    for (i = 0; i < WSIZE; ++i)
        shift[i] = mMinus4;

    h = x[0];
    h = ((h << 1) + x[1]);
    h = ((h << 1) + x[2]);
    h = ((h << 1) + x[3]);
    h = ((h << 1) + x[4]);
    shift[h % WSIZE] = m - RANK5;
    for (i = RANK5; i < mMinus1; ++i) {
        h = x[i - 4];
        h = ((h << 1) + x[i - 3]);
        h = ((h << 1) + x[i - 2]);
        h = ((h << 1) + x[i - 1]);
        h = ((h << 1) + x[i]);
        shift[h % WSIZE] = mMinus1 - i;
    }
    h = x[i - 4];
    h = ((h << 1) + x[i - 3]);
    h = ((h << 1) + x[i - 2]);
    h = ((h << 1) + x[i - 1]);
    h = ((h << 1) + x[i]);
    sh1 = shift[h % WSIZE];
    shift[h % WSIZE] = 0;
    if (sh1 == 0)
        sh1 = 1;
    // END_PREPROCESSING

    // BEGIN_SEARCHING
    i = mMinus1;
    memcpy(y + n, x, m);
    while (1) {
        sh = 1;
        while (sh != 0) {
            h = y[i - 4];
            h = ((h << 1) + y[i - 3]);
            h = ((h << 1) + y[i - 2]);
            h = ((h << 1) + y[i - 1]);
            h = ((h << 1) + y[i]);
            sh = shift[h % WSIZE];
            i += sh;
        }
        if (i < n) {
            j = 0;
            while (j < m && x[j] == y[i - mMinus1 + j])
                j++;
            if (j >= m) {
                count++; // OUTPUT(i-mMinus1);//printf("%d\n", i-mMinus1);count++;//
            }
            i += sh1;
        } else {
            // END_SEARCHING;
            return count;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char *x = "welcometot";
    char *y = "welcometotheStack Overflow,welcometoalllearners...welcome!";
    int m = strlen(x);
    int n = strlen(y);
    printf("\n The number of total matching: %d", search(x, m, y, n));
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is **the code does not generate any output**.

> `hash5.exe` has stopped working

It shows:

> Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH

I found that if `memcpy(y+n, x, m);` is removed, the code works and provide correct output! But why does this happen? Can anyone explain?

The algorithm is presented in the following research article:

*S. Faro: A very fast string matching algorithm based on condensed alphabets, in Algorithmic
Aspects in Information and Management - 10th International Conference, AAIM 2016. Proceedings, vol. 9778 of Lecture Notes in Computer Science, Springer, 2016, pp. 65–76*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because char *y = "some text" will be placed in  read only memory segment by the compile/link process.
Try with char y[] = "some text" or char y[SOME_BIGGER_SIZE] = "some text"

Comment: " in read only memory segment by the compile/link process. "... so what, in linux it works.. Why not in windows or other compiler, also the input format is fixed, there are 170 implementation, each of them abide this rule, I just can not simply change to `char y[]=`

Comment: @Michael In linux under x86_64 compiled by gcc 12.1.1 it doesn't work too. It produces segmentation fault.

Comment: @dimich this segmentation error occurs in some other cases too, there is Linux version of this implementation, I will try that, thanks for your feedback.